# Properly using curl --data-urlencode when passing a variable

Tags: bash, optimization, curl, sed

I'm trying to optimize my code and one particular piece of code is borrowed. I'd like to remove the sed so I'm not using any external processes in my main loop.

```
function sendMsg () {
value=$(echo $1 | sed 's/ /%20/g;s/!/%21/g;s/"/%22/g;s/#/%23/g;s/\&/%26/g;s/'\''/%28/g;s/(/%28/g;s/)/%29/g;s/:/%3A/g;s/\//%2F/g');
str="http://www.xxxx.com/api.ashx?v=1&k=$Key&a=send&w=$value";
curl -s $str;
}
```

I've edited this for clarity. The $value is simply to convert to a proper url for output via the curl command at the end of the function.

While this works just fine, I'm mostly interested in making this as fast to process as possible without forking to outside processes if I can.

Thanks for the comments so far!

Where I'm at so far is this:

```
function sendMsg () {
str="http://www.xxxx.com/api.ashx?v=1&k=$Key&a=send&w=";
curl -s $str --data-urlencode "$1";
}
```

Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: Yes, it would be faster in bash. Even though bash-the-language is slow, starting a subprocess, reading its output, and wait()ing for it to exit is much, _much_ slower than a few tens of parameter expansions.

Comment: ...a microbenchmark (doing either approach in a loop) would be the comprehensive way to answer this, y'know.

Comment: ...that said, if your goal is to implementing correct escaping of arbitrary data for use in forming URLs, I'd argue that the Right Answer is not sed _or_ parameter expansions, but to use a canonical implementation other people have been testing for years in tricky corner cases -- such as Python's `urllib.quote()`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the subject. Would you be able to start me off on how to tackle this?

Comment: ...btw, `echo "$1"` is different from `echo $1` -- the latter will, for instance, replace `*` (when on its own or separated by whitespace) with a list of files in the current directory; replace runs of whitespace (or other whitespace characters such as newlines) with a single space character; and otherwise mangle your data.

Comment: Yes, the code following is to format the $1 to a $value for sending off to a curl process

Comment: in which precise context? curl can often do url-encoding for you, so it's often unnecessary to do it yourself first. Of course, if you're not using correct quoting when invoking curl, shell string-splitting effects can cause bugs that _look_ like they're being caused (or fixed) by urlencoding content.

Comment: You should have considered `--data-urlencode`.

Comment: Trying the curl route if someone wouldn't mind looking at my edited question.

Comment: @yab Your question is already completely different from the previous one. I think you should have just accepted the current answer that fixed it and created another question.

Comment: I'm extremely new at this and had a 'wrong' question from the outset. I apologize if I did something out the norm for the regular users here. Thanks to some comments by @Charles Duffy, he led me to ask the correct question that I needed help with. Is refining your question to what you're actually needing to accomplish not encouraged here? I'm a little confused, sorry.

Comment: Completely replacing your question (as opposed to refining it) after it's already answered is bad practice. Please roll back the changes and ask the new question separately.

Comment: ...by the way, as an aside -- the `function` keyword is somewhat questionable practice, as it makes your scripts incompatible with POSIX sh without adding any benefit over the POSIX function declaration syntax: `myFunc() {`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the answer to your question: If you are doing a single substitution or filtering, using pattern matching is faster:

```
$ foo=${bar/old/new}               # Faster
$ foo=$(sed 's/old/new/' <<<$bar   # Slower
```

The first doesn't require spawning a sub-shell, and running `sed`, then substituting this back into `$foo`. However, if you are doing this almost a dozen times, I believe using `sed` may be faster:

```
value=$(sed -e 's/ /%20/g' \
   -e 's/!/%21/g' \
   -e 's/"/%22/g' \
   -e 's/#/%23/g' \
   -e 's/\&/%26/g' \
   -e 's/'\''/%28/g' \
   -e 's/(/%28/g' \
   -e 's/)/%29/g' \
   -e 's/:/%3A/g' \
   -e 's/\//%2F/g'<<<$1);
```

Note that this syntax is easier to read since each substitution command is on its own line. Also note that `<<<` eliminates the need to echo and pipe.

This only does a single call to `sed` while pattern matching has to be done multiple times.

However, you should be using `--data` and `--data-uuencode` instead of building the query string yourself:

```
$ curl -s http://www.xxxx.com/api.ashx \
    --data v=1 \
    --data k=$Key \
    --data a=send \
    --data-urlencode w="$value";
```

The `--data--urlencode` will encode the value of `$value` for you, so you don't have to do it. Unfortunately, this parameter doesn't exist in all versions of `curl`. It was added in version 7.18.0 back in January of 2008. Run `curl --version` to see what version you have:

```
$ curl --version     # Life is good
curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5

$ curl --version     # David Sad
curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
```

---

## Addendum

> In attempting this I'm getting an 'unsupported API versionERROR', even though my curl --version reports 7.29.0

I can't test what you have, but I decided to try our Jenkins server to see if I can set the build description. I made sure the description has spaces in it, so it requires `--data-urlencoding`. This command worked:

```
$ curl --user dweintraub:swordfish \
    --data Submit=Submit \
    --data-urlencode description="This is my test descripition" \
    http://jenkins.corpwad.com/jenkins/job/Admin-5.1.1/138/submitDescription
```

This is as if I did:

```
$ curl -user "dweintraub:swordfish http://jenkins.corpwad.com/jenkins/job/Admin-5.1.1/138/submitDescription?Submit=Submit&desciption=This%20is%20my%20test%20descripition"
```

Note that `--data` adds the question mark for you.

(No, `swordfish` isn't my password).

It's not as complex as your command, but it might help point out where you're having problems. Do you have a user name and password? If so, you need the `--user` parameter.

Comment: In attempting this I'm getting an 'unsupported API versionERROR', even though my curl --version reports 7.29.0

Comment: Actually it's ERROR: unsupported API version. I'm still investigating.

Comment: `curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP`

Comment: Looks like it's the returned message from the server I'm POSTing to. I'm still investigating the output from curl to see if it's any different from my original example. Does using --data add the '?' after the 'http://www.xxxx.com/api.ashx'?

Comment: See my addendum. There's an example of the command I use. `--data` adds the `?` for you.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum. It looks like from your example, you've moved the URL to the end of the line, which is fine, but the injection of the ? is actually in the wrong place compared to my example. Looks like the ? goes before the 'submitDescription'. According to the website I'm needing to use curl with, the ? goes AFTER my full URL rather than before the api.ashx.

Comment: I figured out the issue. The webserver I'm hitting only accepts GET method. I added -G to the beginning of my line and all is well now. Thanks very much for your help finally get this done.

Comment: @yab Sorry. ***I*** had the `?` in the wrong place. I manually typed in what the URL would look like. I've corrected the URL. I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do this a lot, the overhead of spawning multiple `sed` processes might add up. In that case, you can use the following lines instead:

```
value=${1// /%20/}
value=${value//!/%21}
value=${value//\"/%22}
value=${value//\#/%23}
value=${value//&/%26}
value=${value//\'/%27}
value=${value//(/%28}
value=${value//)/%29}
value=${value//:/%3A}
value=${value//\//%2F}
```

Comment: Would this still be faster than figuring out how to use curl with the --data-urlencode option? (I'm lost on that point too btw :P)

Comment: Using `--data-urlencode` would be faster (and far simpler to maintain) if it is applicable, so I would take the time to investigate.